# MAUI CommunityToolkit raises an error with Popup

Tags: c#, android, maui, maui-community-toolkit

In my `.NET8` `MAUI`, I'm using the `CommunityToolkit` and in particular the `PopUp` function. Everything seems work on my local devices. When I deeply the app in the Google Store, their tests show me that there are a few errors when I call the `PopUp`. I saw in the AppCenter that the errors I get:

> System.ObjectDisposedException: ObjectDisposed_Generic ObjectDisposed_ObjectName_Name, CommunityToolkit.Maui.Core.Views.MauiPopup

and the description is

> Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers.AssertSelf(IJavaPeerable )
> Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers.JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualBooleanMethod(String
> , IJavaPeerable , JniArgumentValue* )
> Android.App.Dialog.get_IsShowing()
> CommunityToolkit.Maui.Core.Handlers.PopupHandler.MapOnClosed(PopupHandler
> handler, IPopup view, Object result)
> Microsoft.Maui.CommandMapper`2.<>c__DisplayClass6_0[[CommunityToolkit.Maui.Core.IPopup,
> CommunityToolkit.Maui.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null],[CommunityToolkit.Maui.Core.Handlers.PopupHandler,
> CommunityToolkit.Maui.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null]].b__0(IElementHandler h, IElement v, Object
> o) Microsoft.Maui.CommandMapper.InvokeCore(String key, IElementHandler
> viewHandler, IElement virtualView, Object args)
> Microsoft.Maui.CommandMapper.Invoke(IElementHandler viewHandler,
> IElement virtualView, String property, Object args)
> Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ElementHandler.Invoke(String command, Object
> args)
> CommunityToolkit.Maui.Views.Popup.CommunityToolkit.Maui.Core.IPopup.OnClosed(Object
> result) CommunityToolkit.Maui.Views.Popup.OnClosed(Object result,
> Boolean wasDismissedByTappingOutsideOfPopup, CancellationToken token)
> CommunityToolkit.Maui.Views.Popup.CloseAsync(Object result,
> CancellationToken token)
> CommunityToolkit.Maui.Views.Popup.Close(Object result)
> System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.b__128_0(Object state)
> Android.App.SyncContext.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.b__0()
> Java.Lang.Thread.RunnableImplementor.Run()
> Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run(IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this)
> Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PP_V(_JniMarshal_PP_V
> callback, IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr klazz)

I don't know how to find out from where the exception occurs. I noticed that the `PopUp` is not always responsive. For example, if I call the popup with

```
var loadingPopup = new LoadingPopup();
Application.Current.MainPage.ShowPopup(loadingPopup);
```

and then immediately

```
loadingPopup.Close();
```

the popup is still there and there is no way to close it. Is there any alternative to implement the `PopUp` without using the `CommunityToolkit` that works for all platforms (Windows & macOS included)?

Comment: Can you create a Github replica of this i need to see what you are doing here